# Share encrypted AMIs across accounts to launch instances to be used with ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2

Following on from the recent announcement from AWS about [sharing encrypted AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/share-encrypted-amis-across-accounts-to-launch-instances-in-a-single-step/)

Been testing this today, shared the encrypted AMI and KMS key.
It worked when I launched a single instance from the console using the shared encrypted AMI.

Although trying to use the same shared encrypted AMI in an ASG produced the following error message, has anyone else seen this?

```
Launching a new EC2 instance: i-0a306b1c0c65fb197. Status Reason: Instance became unhealthy while waiting for instance to be in InService state. Termination Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASG service linked role needs access to the CMK as detail in case 2, solution 2 of the following forum thread.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=277523

Comment: The given link is dead.

Comment: Hardly surprising since it was 4 years ago and things have moved on in AWS land.
This is a more recent article https://binx.io/2020/01/20/how-to-start-autoscaling-groups-using-a-cross-account-encrypted-ami/